# How to mock aggregate function result with JOOQ?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jooq

I call the count aggregate function in my service class using JOOQ.

```
SelectQuery<Record> query = this.dsl.selectQuery();
query.addSelect(DSL.count());
query.addFrom(SOME_TABLE);
final Integer total = query.fetchOne(0, Integer.class);
```

I need to mock count result in my unit test.
What is the best way to do that?

Following [jooq documentation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.5/manual/tools/jdbc-mocking/#N2B72F), I have to create result record with relevant fields count. 
Something like that:

```
Result<Record1<Integer>> result = create.newResult(...);
```

But what I have to use as the `create.newResult()` method parameters in case of creating the mock record for aggregate function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should return one row with one column, so create that result:

```
Field<Integer> c = DSL.count();
Result<Record1<Integer>> result = create.newResult(c);
result.add(create.newRecord(c).values(42));
```

The documentation you've linked shows a very similar example:

```
...
// You decide, whether any given statement returns results, and how many
else if (sql.toUpperCase().startsWith("SELECT")) {

    // Always return one record
    Result<Record2<Integer, String>> result = create.newResult(AUTHOR.ID,AUTHOR.LAST_NAME);
    result.add(create
        .newRecord(AUTHOR.ID, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME)
        .values(1, "Orwell"));
    mock[0] = new MockResult(1, result);
}
...
```